# Firebase app check in python AWS lambda not working because of cryptography compilation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, firebase-admin, firebase-app-check

I am trying to validate App Check tokens from my AWS lambda in python under the x86_64 architecture.

When i execute my AWS lambda, i got the following error :

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /var/task/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so: invalid ELF header
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70649979/migrate-to-arm64-on-aws-lambda-show-error-unable-to-import-module-encryptor-la) but i am working on MacOS x86_64 so i have the same architecture as the target.

How can i solve this issue since it seems i have compiled it in the correct architecture ?

Note : I know that this is from Firebase App Check because it's the only dependency i have in my lambda and if i remove it everything is fine.

EDIT : here is my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75644507/python-aws-lambda-in-error-because-of-pyjwtcrypto-cryptography) very related to this one. If someone answers the other, i will just have to compile `firebase-admin` on my docker ubuntu container.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same issue, in my case I was using M1 Mac.
To fix this I used the following code to install firebase-admin

```
pip install \
    --platform manylinux2014_aarch64 \
    --target=./package \
    --implementation cp \
    --python 3.9 \
    --only-binary=:all: --upgrade \
    firebase-admin
```

If you are using x86_64, you can use the following:

```
pip install \
    --platform manylinux2014_2014_x86_64 \
    --target=./python/lib/python3.9/site-packages \
    --implementation cp \
    --python 3.9 \
    --only-binary=:all: --upgrade \
    firebase-admin
```

Comment: It will stop work of other dependent of all other packages of python.