# Python AWS Lambda in error because of pyjwt[crypto] (cryptography)

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, aws-lambda, python-cryptography

I have the following error when i run my AWS lambda under python 3.9 :

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /var/task/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I am aware that this is somehow a compilation issue so here the steps i have done until the AWS lambda deployment :

- Create a Dockerfile :

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV TZ=Europe/Paris
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
# Install py39 from deadsnakes repository
RUN apt-get install python3.9 -y
# Install pip from standard ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN apt-get install zip -y

RUN apt-get install libc6 -y

RUN mkdir /home/packages

RUN pip install --target=/home/packages pyjwt[crypto]==2.6.0 
RUN pip install --target=/home/packages pymongo[srv]==4.3.3
```

- Inside the docker container, i do : `cd /home/packages`
- Then : `zip -r ../package.zip .`
- Then i use `docker cp` to copy the `package.zip` to my MacOS host.

I use `zip -g package.zip lambda_function.py` and i upload the `.zip` file using boto3.

[image]

I would like to know why this is not enough or what am i missing here ?

Note : i need to keep using the `zip` method to upload the lambda package for other reasons, unless there is no other choice of course..

EDIT : In response to @Tom 's answer if i add the mentioned `pip` command in my `Dockerfile` :

```
 > [12/14] RUN pip install --platform --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --implementation cp --python 3.9 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade --target /home/packages cryptography:                                                      
#19 3.185 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement manylinux2014_x86_64 (from versions: none)
#19 3.186 ERROR: No matching distribution found for manylinux2014_x86_64
```

Comment: There may be several reasons. Hope here you can find the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340921/aws-error-from-python-no-module-named-lambda-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're installing pyjwt[crypto] in an Ubuntu container but this environment is going to be totally different to your AWS Lamda environment.

AWS Lambda does not provide the `.so` libraries that the cryptography module is expecting. When you run `pip install` on an ubuntu system, pip assumes that the module will be executed on the current platform and takes the required system libraries for granted.

To address this, we can make pip do the heavy lifting for us, the cryptography package comes with a `manylinux2014_x86_64` platform that ships with the required libraries:

```
RUN pip install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --implementation cp --python 3.9 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade --target /home/packages cryptography
RUN pip install --target=/home/packages pyjwt[crypto]==2.6.0 
RUN pip install --target=/home/packages pymongo[srv]==4.3.3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! i update the question with the error i am getting using this new `pip` cmd. 
I also understand that i should simply choose a different linux distribution ? Which one would do the job if not ubuntu (for AWS Lambda) ? Debian ?

Comment: @Tom3652 have a read of this Amazon documentation: [AWS Lamda Containers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html). Also, I had a typo in my answer, can you try again now please?

Comment: The goal for this sort of task is to have your build environment match your runtime environment as much as possible. It looks like the Lambda containers also come with an emulator to test your Lambda function locally too, which is handy.

Comment: Thank you very much it's working very fine and i understand about the environment now :) really appreciate your help !